# How to put docker container for database on a different host in production?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Let's say we have a simple web app stack, something like the one described in `docker-compse` docs. Its `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This is great for development on a laptop. In production, though, it would be useful to require the db container to be on its own host. Tutorials I'm able to find use `docker-swarm` to scale out the web container, but pay no attention to the fact that the instance of `db` and one instance of `web` run on the same machine.

Is it possible to require a specific container to be on its own machine (or even better, on a specific machine) using `docker` ? If so, how? If not, what is the docker way to deal with database in multi-container apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, databases sit on the edge of the container world, they're useful for development and testing but production databases are often not very ephemeral or portable things by nature. [Flocker](https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/) certainly
helps as do scalable types of databases, like Cassandra, but databases can have very specific requirements that might be better treated as a service that sits behind your containerised app ([RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) etc).

In any case you will need a container orchestration tool.

You can apply [manual scheduling constraints](https://docs.docker.com/compose/swarm/#manual-scheduling) for Compose + Swarm to dictate the docker host a container can run on. For your database, you might have:

```
environment:
  - "constraint:storage==ssd"
```

Otherwise you can setup a more static Docker environment with [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/), [Puppet](https://puppet.com/)

Use another orchestration tool that supports docker: [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/), [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/), [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/)

Use a container service: [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/), [Docker Cloud/Tutum](https://cloud.docker.com/)